# Count the numbers between 999 and 10000 subject to

Tags: combinatorics

Question: Count the numbers between 999 and 10000 subject to the condition atleast one digit is repeated

My work:
4 digits are same: $9$ nos.

3 digits are same: $252$ nos.

2 digits are same:
Suppose number starts with 1
Then 1xxy, 1xyx, 1yxx (x, y  are not 1). This format comprises $3 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 = 216$ nos.

11xy, 1yx1, 1x1y. This format comprises $9 \cdot 8 = 72$ nos.

Total (for numbers starting with 1) = $288$

Total (for numbers  starting with 1-9) = $288 * 9 = 2592$ nos

Answer = $9 + 252 + 2592 = 2853$

Correct Answer = $4464$

Comment: You haven't counted numbers of the form $xxyy, xyyx,$ or $xyxy$.  Also, how did you determine there are only $252$ numbers with a digit repeated $3$ times?  I don't think that number is correct.

Comment: @RobertShore Thanks for the inputs. Now I counted correctly.  Yes, it is 324 not 252

Comment: Here's how I counted:                           4 digits are same: Count = 9nos.;                                                   3 digits are same: xxxy, xxyx, xyxx, yxxx - each 9 * 9 = 81. Count= 4 * 81 = 324 nos. ;                                            2 digits are same(1 pair): xxyk, xyxk, xykx, yxkx, ykxx, yxxk. Count = 6 * 9 * 9 * 8 = 3888 nos. ;                                                    2 digits are same(2 pairs): xxyy, xyxy, xyyx. Any other combination is a duplicate. Count= 3 * 9 * 9 = 243 nos.                                                  Total Count = 4464

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simpler approach.

Between $999$ and $10000$ (excluding both), there are a total of $9000$ numbers. And the number of four-digit numbers with no repeated digits is $9 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 = 4536$.

So the number of numbers with at least one digit repeated equals $9000 - 4536 = 4464$.